# Is Microsemi Libero supposed to have many arithmetic cores inside its catalogue?

Tags: microsemi-fpga, libero

Here is a screenshot of the Libero catalogue tab in my machine.

[image]

I am using Libero 11.9. There are only 3 design blocks which frankly are trivial. There is no divider, no floating point maths blocks, no square root or complex number maths blocks. Do such IP cores exist at all for the Microsemi devices? I am using IGLOO2. What am I missing?

Comment: As someone who deals with optimizing FIR filters: A good FIR implementation, or a good CORDIC are far from trivial. Why would you want floating point math on your control- and sample-processing oriented FPGA? Usually, that's a sign of "I try to do exactly the same thing as in software, but on an FPGA", and that's rarely a path to success. Most things can very well be done in fixed-point, if you sit down and write the bit-widening and necessary bit depth at every step in your data processing chain.

Comment: I usually use Intel/Altera FPGAs and am kind of new to Microsemi flash based FPGAs. I find a few things very strange which is what prompted this question. I do not need to implement any complex math functions at the moment but maybe it will be required in the future. Since Intel/Altera provide so many arithmetic function blocks, I am not sure why Microsemi does not provide them. They do have rather complex IP for video processing and some other stuff but no divided or floating point unit IP???

Comment: yes, that sounds realistic. Different target markets; different marketing strategy, too. Never let anyone tell you that an FPGA manufacturer isn't a software company; they really really are. So, for some companies it pays to invest R&D into supplying float math blocks (especially kinda exotic ones like a division) for others, it doesn't.

Comment: I had thought that since floating point maths blocks have been already invented, it would take only a small team of people to port it to Microsemi devices and create an IP for it. hmmm

Comment: Sure, you can just synthesize a trivial IEEE754-ish library, there's enough. But it makes no difference whether microsemi does that for you, or you just use such a library in your code yourself. This would only be a bonus, if at microsemi, someone sat down and optimized the float operations for the hardware that's actually in the FPGA, which really is non-trivial.

Comment: All FPGAs nowadays contain LUT and registers with hardware multipliers. Then why can't we just rely on the synthesis tool to do the optimization?

Comment: Because "just rely on the synthesis tool" isn't really working out for floating point numbers; it's not that easy. You want defined behaviour for all kind of special cases. You want an optimized architecture for operations. "Just rely on the synthesis tool" is like saying "they should eat cake": They would have to implement float-sensible optimization in their tools, first.

Comment: What I meant is, if one person or company has written the RTL code, then the rest should just implement it on their hardware. The synthesis and fitter will take care of the rest. Is this not true?

Comment: yes, that is not true: the synthesis tool needs to be aware of what you want to do. It's really not that easy to implement a *good* floating point IP core library on a given hardware. It is even harder to implement a good synthesizer for this kind of problem.

Comment: Is there a research paper or some resource that might explain why this is so, usually we just write RTL code and click on compile. Occasionally we might need to use specific hard IP blocks that cannot be inferred from the RTL code.

Comment: OK, you just say "we click on compile". So, someone else wrote that compiler/synthesizer/mapper. Right? That's the problem you need to solve first. Synthesizer design. Hard stuff. Xilinx, Altera/Intel and others get it wrong all the time. Think: Compiler design, but with hardware constraints and much more degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

Microsemi confirmed that all those cores I mentioned above do not exist. I am working with IGLOO2 platform. They said there is a divider core in alpha or beta testing but not released yet. So we are limited to multipliers for now.